# AS3Common Bytecode + ASC2

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm using the as3common bytecode library to inspect swf files. But for some reason it doesn't work with swf files created with the asc2 compiler. Does somebody has a solution for this?

The line `ByteCodeType.fromByteArray(loaderInfo.bytes);` throws this error:

```
Exception fault: RangeError: Error #1125: The index 129 is out of range 127.
    at org.as3commons.bytecode.io::AbstractAbcDeserializer/deserializeConstantPool()[/Users/smorales/Documents/Data/dev/workspaces/educalabs/WorkerFromClass/src/org/as3commons/bytecode/io/AbstractAbcDeserializer.as:248]
    at org.as3commons.bytecode.io::AbcDeserializer/deserialize()[/Users/smorales/Documents/Data/dev/workspaces/educalabs/WorkerFromClass/src/org/as3commons/bytecode/io/AbcDeserializer.as:122]
    at org.as3commons.bytecode.tags.serialization::DoABCSerializer/read()[/Users/smorales/Documents/Data/dev/workspaces/educalabs/WorkerFromClass/src/org/as3commons/bytecode/tags/serialization/DoABCSerializer.as:63]
    at org.as3commons.bytecode.swf::SWFWeaverFileIO/readTag()[/Users/smorales/Documents/Data/dev/workspaces/educalabs/WorkerFromClass/src/org/as3commons/bytecode/swf/SWFWeaverFileIO.as:158]
    at org.as3commons.bytecode.swf::SWFWeaverFileIO/read()[/Users/smorales/Documents/Data/dev/workspaces/educalabs/WorkerFromClass/src/org/as3commons/bytecode/swf/SWFWeaverFileIO.as:120]
    at WorkerFromClass/initTests()[/Users/smorales/Documents/Data/dev/workspaces/educalabs/WorkerFromClass/src/WorkerFromClass.as:31]
    at WorkerFromClass()[/Users/smorales/Documents/Data/dev/workspaces/educalabs/WorkerFromClass/src/WorkerFromClass.as:22]
```

I already tried to find more infos about the usage but it seems so that the official site is down: http://www.as3commons.org.

Thank you very much